# I have some issue when I try to use pyttsx3

Tags: python-3.8

**When I run the code, it doesn't give an error and doesn't say anything. I checked the speaker and everything is fine**
**Here my code:**

```
import pttsx3

speak = 'Hello world'

saying = pyttsx3.init()
saying.say(speak)
saying.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Before posting questions please take a look at the post about how to ask a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. When asking questions make sure you have a description of the problem in the title, and list what you have done to try to fix the problem, as well as what you want/expect to happen. In this case it looks like a typo as noted by the other answer so you could probably close this question as it probably won't help other users. Take care and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import pttsx3 <--- Missing y in the library, working properly after add it

import pyttsx3

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I fixed it and it still doesn't work